# Stochastic sample using randsample?

Tags: matlab, stochastic-process

I'd like to make a stochastic step simulation for P and I with `randsample` like this simple one below.

```
P=zeros(1,5); I=zeros(1,5)
```

%easy way

```
for i=1:5
X=rand; dt=0.01; 

a=randi(50,1);  
b=randi(50,1);
c=randi(50,1);
d=randi(50,1);



if X<=a*dt, 
   P(i+1)=P(i+1)+1;
elseif X>a*dt && X<=(a+b)*dt
   P(i+1)=P(i)-1;
elseif X>(a+b)*dt && X<=(a+b+c)*dt
   I(i+1)=I(i)-1;
elseif X>(a+b+c)*dt && X<=(a+b+c+d)*dt
   I(i+1)=I(i)+1;       
else  %do nothing
  P(i+1)=P(i);
  I(i+1)=P(i);
end
```

%Using `randsample`

```
    Pvec=[a b c d (some value for doing nothing)]*dt;
    Pvec=Pvec./sum(Pvec);
    s=randsample(1:5,1,'true',Pvec);
```

This isn't correct. How would you do it efficiently?

This is what I'm trying to do, but I don't think it's quite right...
[image]

**UPDATE with competing populations I and P code** Based this set of equations.

[image]

```
theta_P=0.15;delta_P=0.01;alpha_I=0.4;gamma_I=0.01;delta_I=0.005;lambda_I=0.05;
m=100;   % # runs
time=10; % # Total time of simulation
dt=0.01; % # Time step
D=6000; T=10/dt;

P=zeros(m,time/dt); I=zeros(m,time/dt);

for i=1:m
 for j=1:time/dt         
  arrivalI=alpha_I+P(i,j)*lambda_I;
  lossI=I(i,j)*gamma_I+P(i,j)*I(i,j)*delta_I;

     if j<=T
        alpha_P=D/T;
     else
        alpha_P=0;
     end

  arrivalP=alpha_P+P(i,j)*theta_P;
  lossP=P(i,j)*I(i,j)*delta_P;


  X=rand;

Pvec=[arrivalI lossI arrivalP lossP]*dt;%
Pvec=Pvec./sum(Pvec);

s=randsample(1:4,1,'true',Pvec);


if s==1
    I(i,j+1)=I(i,j)+1;%;
    P(i,j+1)=P(i,j);
elseif s==2
    I(i,j+1)=I(i,j)-1;%
    P(i,j+1)=P(i,j);
elseif s==3

    P(i,j+1)=P(i,j)+1;%
    I(i,j+1)=I(i,j);
elseif s==4

    P(i,j+1)=P(i,j)-1;%;
    I(i,j+1)=I(i,j);
else

    P(i,j+1)=P(i,j);  %check
    I(i,j+1)=I(i,j);
end


end

   subplot(2,2,1:2)
%     
   if P(i,j)>5
   loglog(abs(P(i,:)),'-r')
%    
   else
    loglog(abs(P(i,:)),'-b')
%          
   end
  hold on 
  axis([1 1e3 1 1e4])
end
```

Comment: In your statement `if X<=a*dt`, `a` is an array. Is that intentional?

Comment: @Jonas No you're right, it's actually only supposed to be a single value evaluated at every iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can replicate your first code block "the easy way" with a call to `randsample`.

The first code block generates `P` and `I` recursively.

Whilst, [randsample](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/stats/randsample.html) generates samples with or without replacement of the population: `1:5` in this case.

You may want to try [randseq](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/bioinfo/ref/randseq.html) (requires the Bioinformatics Toolbox). In terms of efficiency, in general there is no way to vectorize a recursive operation.

Comment: Thanks for having a look at this.  Basically it's for solving a deterministic equation stochastically. Have you ever come across this in matlab by using randsample or randseq?  Or indeed some other method not like %easy way?

Comment: Due to the nature of recursive problems, all methods that produce the required output will effectively be the `% easy way'. If you need to accelerate the simulation check out some of the [Matlab Coder](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder/) technologies.